# Changing the within-group order of a grouped bar plot in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'd like to change the order of my within-group variable in a plotly bar plot in Python.
For example, how can I switch the order of lunch and dinner here?

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.bar(df, x='sex', y='total_bill', color='time', barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

[image]

`categoryorder` can only change the order of groups, i.e. Male and Female.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort the `df` in descending order basis the column `time`.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
df.sort_values(['time'],ascending=[False],inplace=True)
fig = px.bar(df, x='sex', y='total_bill', color='time', barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: In my case, I have Fall and Winter bars. I want the Winter bars to be on the right, but I want the grouped bars to be sorted by the Winter values, not the Fall ones. Is it possible to achieve this within Plotly? If I sort my DataFrame so that the Fall values are on top, the Winter values appear on the right, but the bars are sorted by the highest 'Fall' values.